# dynamic class div has two set of css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the div generated dynamically

```
<div class="test-1">1</div>
<div class="test-2">2</div>
<div class="test-3">3</div>
 ...
<div class="test-100">100</div>
<div class="test-101">101</div>
```

I want to display class test-1 to test-50 in red color
 and test-51 and above should be in green.Is it possible to handle with constraint css or I may need to use in jquery css

Comment: You can have two classes if that IMHO poorly chosen numerical is a challenge but used for other things like a class list with "test-group-a test-1" then later "test-group-b test-51" and thus simplify the entire thing.  This really is what CSS is about in many cases, "stuff the same gets the same class"

Comment: I am adding more than one duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO `nth-of-class` selector. So you cannot use that, but if all the elements are in order and all are siblings, you could something with `:nth-child(n+x)`

You set up a default color for the elements 1-50 ( red ) and then change the color for the ones from 51 and above. Use `:nth-child(n + 51)`

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-child(n+4) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1">1</div>
<div class="test-2">2</div>
<div class="test-3">3</div>
<div class="test-4">4</div>
<div class="test-5">5</div>
<div class="test-5">6</div>
```

OR IF you know the class of the element at position `51`, you could use `~` general sibling selector. Which selects all the siblings of the element that are after it ( down the DOM tree )

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

div.test-3 ~ div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1">1</div>
<div class="test-2">2</div>
<div class="test-3">3</div>
<div class="test-4">4</div>
<div class="test-5">5</div>
<div class="test-6">6</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you able to modify html generation, better solution will be to add different classes to first 50 and other 50 elements.

```html
<div class="test-1 red">1</div>
<div class="test-2 red">2</div>
...
<div class="test-51 green">51</div>
...
<div class="test-100 green">100</div>
```

Other solutions have heavy downsides.

While you can manually write

```css
.test-1,
.test-2,
...
.test-50 {
  color: green;
}
```

It probably not what you want.

Such CSS can be automated with preprocessor or postprocessor if you use some.
For example, with SASS

```
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .test-#{i} {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

But it leads to very unoptimized CSS.

You also can add new classes ("green" and "red") or apply style directly with jQuery, but it will be applied after JS execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second class to classes `test-1` to `test-50` and for classes `test-51` to above like:

```
.redColor{
    background-color: red;
}

.greenColor{
    background-color: green;
}

<div class="test-1 redColor">1</div>
<div class="test-2 redColor">2</div>
<div class="test-3 redColor">3</div>
 ...
<div class="test-100 greenColor">100</div>
<div class="test-101 greenColor">101</div>
```

Or you can use css preprocessors like [`sass`](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: or perhaps "red-color" since that is the pattern in use already for class names.

Comment: yes, you can use `red-color`, `redColor` or `r-color` class name can be anything.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss was referring to  using`name-name` instead of `nameName`  it's a naming convention to use `kebab-case` for HTML attributes. `camelCase` should be used for naming variables and functions.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving class names as test-1, test-2 ...., you should give two classnames for two set of divs i.e. for =<50 and >50 depending upon the index of the loop.

e.g. considering your code to be dynamically creating divs using map, the code with just 10 divs can look like:

`

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(index => (
  <div className={ index > 5 ? 'green' : 'red' }>{index}</div>
))
```

`